# How to get the text within the a tag present in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the text present in anchor tag which is present in javascript variable.

`var a= <a href="javascript:downloadPopup('9374227','CASE','1004030422')">9374227</a>`
i want **"9374227"**
How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a` can be made as a string, use jQuery [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
var a = '<a href="javascript:downloadPopup(\'9374227\',\'CASE\',\'1004030422\')">9374227</a>';

var jQueryAnchor = $(a);//convert to jquery object
var text = jQueryAnchor.text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It will give you the result as expected.

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');

    temp.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:downloadPopup(\'9374227\',\'CASE\',\'1004030422\')">9374227</a>';

var number = temp.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

console.log(number);
```